# How do I reinstate visibility of hidden Shiny output?

Tags: r, shiny, hidden

I tried this solution to suppress an error in a Shiny app:

```
tags$style(type="text/css",
         ".shiny-output-error { visibility: hidden; }",
         ".shiny-output-error:before { visibility: hidden; }"
)
```

How do I reverse this? Unfortunately, it is hiding my plot.

Comment: Why don't you rather fix this error?

Comment: The error arises due to the way I manipulate a function (heemod::define_transition) to make it work with an interactive matrix. I have achieved the effect I wanted, but wanted to avoid having an erroneous error message appearing. In case you want to review this for yourself, the Shiny app code is here: https://github.com/cobleg/MarkovchainDiagramCreator/blob/master/R_code

Comment: I think adding a `req(input$matrix1)` before line 45 of your R code fixes the error.

Comment: Thanks Bas, that's brilliant! Your suggestion of ```req(input$matrix1) ``` solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the full code including Bas' remedy:

```
# Objective: app that creates Markov chain diagrams based on user input 

library(heemod)
library(diagram)
library(shiny)
library(shinyMatrix)

ui=shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Markov Diagram Creator"),
  fluidRow(
    sidebarPanel(
      textAreaInput("statenames_1",label = "Enter state names here...", value = "H, S1, S2, D"),
      
      hr(),
      tags$h4("Enter state probability transition matrix here: "),
      uiOutput("matrix")
      
      
    ), # end of sidebarPanel
    
    mainPanel(
      
      hr(),
      plotOutput("plot")
      
      
    ) # end of mainPanel
  )))

server=function(input,output){
  
  output$matrix <-renderUI({
    
    states <- unlist( strsplit( x=input$statenames_1, split = "[[:punct:]]" ))
    statenames <- list(states, states)
    m <- (matrix( c(0), length( states ), length( states ), dimnames = statenames ))  
    m1 <- matrixInput("matrix1", rows = list( names = T, editableNames = F ), cols = list( names = T, editableNames = F ),
                      value =  m )
    m1
  })
  
  
  mTM_List <- reactive({
    req(input$matrix1)
    mTM <- as.list( ( as.numeric( t( input$matrix1 ) ) ) )
    mTM$state_names <- ( as.character( rownames( input$matrix1  )))
    mTM
  })
  
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    plot(do.call( define_transition,   mTM_List() ) , cex=0.75, ylim = c(0,.4))
    
  })
```